# Lambda within assert

Tags: c++, lambda, assert

is it somehow possible to use a lambda within a call to `assert()` ?

When i try the following...

```
assert([&]() -> bool{
        sockaddr_storage addr; int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
        return (getsockname(this->m_Socket, (sockaddr*)&addr, &addrlen) != 0) ? false : true;
    });
```

... i get the error

> error C2675: unary '!' : '`anonymous-namespace'::' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the
>   predefined operator

Comment: Sure, but why? Why not just do your work and then check it?

Comment: Have you tried static_assert?

Comment: @galadog: How would that fix it? That's at compile time.

Comment: Others have given you the answer for how to call a lambda immediately. But why would you want to create an anonymous function just to call it? If it is being able to use a block of code in an expression, if you're using GCC, consider using the Statement Expressions extension (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). Although they don't work in all circumstances under C++, I believe they will work in this example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, but assert really only wants a boolean; not a lambda, so you'll have to call it yourself (this assuming that your lambda is one that returns something you want to assert):

```
assert(([&]() -> bool{
        sockaddr_storage addr; int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
        return getsockname(this->m_Socket, (sockaddr*)&addr, &addrlen) == 0;
    })());
```

Comment: ahh ok, lambdas are new to me... did not think about it...

thank you very much!

Comment: @Incubbus: Note the newly added return statement as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can't assert that the lambda itself is "true", since lambdas have no concept of truthiness.

If you want to invoke the lambda and assert that its return value was true, then you need to invoke it:

```
assert([&]() -> bool{
    sockaddr_storage addr; int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    return getsockname(this->m_Socket, (sockaddr*)&addr, &addrlen) == 0;
}());
 ^^
```

I've also changed the second line of the lambda into something that makes a little more sense than your code.